# Can't reference a column in a pd.DataFrame eventhough it is in df.columns

Tags: pandas

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

abs_path = r'C:\Users\strajaku\Desktop\Porto_taxi_data_training.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(abs_path)

print(df.columns)
print(df['TRIP_ID'])
```

The first print returns this:

```
Index(['TRIP_ID,CALL_TYPE,ORIGIN_CALL,ORIGIN_STAND,TAXI_ID,TIMESTAMP,DAY_TYPE,MISSING_DATA,POLYLINE'], dtype='object')
```

But the second one returns this error:

> KeyError: 'TRIP_ID'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is problem you have only one column called `TRIP_ID,CALL_TYPE,ORIGIN_CALL,ORIGIN_STAND,TAXI_ID,TIMESTAMP,DAY_TYPE,MISSING_DATA,POLYLINE`.

Comment: you have only one column: `TRIP_ID,CALL_TYPE,ORIGIN_CALL,ORIGIN_STAND,TAXI_ID,TIMESTAMP,DAY_TYPE,MISSING_DATA,POLYLINE`

Comment: Thanks guys, now I see it :)